# Example for Poisson algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

A linear map $\phi : A \to B$ is called a Poisson morphism if
$\phi : (A, ·) \to (B, ·)$ is a commutative algebra morphism and $\phi : (A, \{, \}) \to (B, \{, \})$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism. Can you please give an example of morphism of Poisson algebras satisfying both of this conditions? Thank you.

Comment: Take $\phi=0$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Poisson algebras are the foundations to go to Poisson manifolds (i.e. manifolds endowed with a Poisson algebra structure on their space of smooth functions), I can give you some interesting examples in this setting.

---

- Linear Poisson manifolds - duals of Lie algebras: Given a Lie algebra map $\phi:\mathfrak g\to \mathfrak h$, its dual $\phi^*:\mathfrak h*\to\mathfrak g^*$ is a Poisson map.
- Diffeomorphisms: A diffeomorphism $\phi:M\to N$ between two smooth manifolds can be naturally lifted to a diffeomorphism $\phi_*:T^*N\to T^*M$ over $\phi$. This map preserves the Liouville 1-form $\theta$ on the cotangent bundle and so it preserves canonical symplectic form $d\theta$, which makes it a Poisson isomorphism.
- Direct product of Poisson manifolds: Given two Poisson manifolds $M_1,M_2$, the product Poisson structure on $M_1\times M_2$ comes with the projection maps $p_i:M_1\times M_2\to M_i$ which are Poisson maps.